# Getting the count of substrings from a list of million words

Tags: java

I am trying to get the count of substrings present in a list of million words in java. Looping through each of these strings to check if the previous value contains the next value seems to have a major performance issue. With fewer words, it works fine but when a huge list of say a million words is involved, it takes ages to give the count back. Can someone tell me the fastest approach to this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are looking for? Please also show some code showing your performance issue.

Comment: Please provide an example for `if the previous value contains the next value`

Comment: Is this substring given at the input or you think of finding common parts of strings in, presumably, a set?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get it in 2N time.

1. Loop throw all list and concatenate string into one or put it line by line into file or sth. that you can get ONE_BIG string containing all words. If string is to big, use file and run regexp via unix.
2. Loop throw all words and use regexp with your word on ONE_BIG and count it.

This is my simple idea. But maybe someone have better. I am waiting with curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be to insert all substrings in a `Set`,and then check the size of the set.

If that is too slow, or rather too memory consuming, a custom datatype, for instance  a balanced tree of characters might be faster.

I would guess that a tree with about 100 million substrings is just about possible to store in a 32 bit jvm.

For larger data sets than that, maybe a hash sieving algorithm might be able to go a bit further for a in memory solution.

A decent database or datastore can be used to index and store the substrings.

There are also [external sort algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) that can sort all substrings using a few files and almost no memory at all..

Actually, if you are using unix or linux,  it's enough to write a program that generate all substrings, pipe it through `sort -q` and `wc` and get an answer probably faster and without almost no coding at all. But that won't get you through the lab I suppose.